# How to remove tick labels from only one axis of a Frame?

Tags: plotting, ticks

This code creates a plot with a frame, ticks, and labels, and with axis numbering on both axes.  I would like to suppress the numbering on the vertical axis.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}
 ,PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 25}}
 ,Frame -> True
 ,PlotStyle -> {{ Thickness -> 0.008, Black}}
 ,FrameStyle -> Thick
 ,LabelStyle -> {Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}
 ,FrameLabel -> {{"  ", " "}, {"T", "  "}}
]
```

Comment: `FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}]`?

Comment: `FrameTicks` removes the numbering as well as the ticks. If you want to remove only the numbers, add `FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], 
   Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`.

Answer (score 7):

`FrameTicksStyle` is the solution here:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 25}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness -> 0.008, Black}}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{" ", " "}, {"T", " "}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], 
    Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

---

Note that `FrameTicks -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}` removes the numbering as well as the ticks altogether:

[image]

---

`ImagePadding -> 1` can be a quick way to remove numbering from all axes leaving the ticks:

[image]

but doesn't work well when one wants to get rid of the numbering on only one axis; adding `ImagePadding -> {{1, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}` gives (note a cut from the left on the "0")

[image]